# Visual Studio Extension highlight based on passed in code block

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

Trying to write a visual studio extension that will let me pass in a string and value pair and highlight the value.

I have an extension that looks for specific code and example is that it runs and might returns all if statements

```
If(someString == someOtherString){
  return “This was something”;
}

If(someStringElse == someOtherString){
  return “This was interesting”;
}
```

In this example my value might be the open parentheses that is part of

```
If(someString
```

I played around with the tutorial on the MSDN site but it seems to only show an all or nothing.  I can get it to highlight all open parentheses and I cannot seem to limit it to only the code block I want (pass in the code blocks I want to search for)

Comment: I'm confused what you want here, and I'm also suspicious this is an "XY problem" where you really want to solve something different here. Which tutorial were you using? This seems like the standard Find feature can more or less find what statements you want...

Comment: I was going off this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd885121(v=vs.110).aspx to try and learn about extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're following that prototype, then you can adjust these lines here:

```
//Find the new spans
FindData findData = new FindData(currentWord.GetText(), currentWord.Snapshot);
findData.FindOptions = FindOptions.WholeWord | FindOptions.MatchCase;

wordSpans.AddRange(TextSearchService.FindAll(findData));
```

`TextSearchService.FindAll` is returning the list of spans in the editor that matched the text passed in. Nothing is stopping you from simply changing the spans or computing new ones before calling `AddRange`. Customize that logic to whatever you want. Obviously, if what you want to highlight doesn't depend upon the position of the caret, there's a fair bit of code you can delete for the determination of `currentWord`.